# Problem with java List<>

Tags: java, list, arraylist, genetic-algorithm

I am not familiar much with the java List and arrayList .. i just need something to work smoothly to append and sort.

My algorithm is simple:

```
set a father string 
add father to speciesList
    mutate father to some new child
    make this new child the future father
    go to step 2
```

The definitions of `ga_` and `ga_struct` is given here

```
public class ga_struct {

    public String gene;
    public int fitness;

}


public class ga_{

    public List<ga_struct> vector= new ArrayList<ga_struct>();

        public void sortspecies()
        {
        Collections.sort(vector,new Comparator<ga_struct>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ga_struct o1, ga_struct o2) {
            int res;
            if(o1.fitness<o2.fitness)
                res=-1;
            else if(o1.fitness>o2.fitness)
                res=1;
            else 
                res=0;
            return res;
                 }
              }
                  );

     }


    public ga_struct mutate(ga_struct parent)
    {
        Random r= new Random();
        ......     do some modification to the parent
        return parent;
    }
}
```

I have been doing this

```
        ga_ newSpecies = new ga_();
        Random r= new Random(10);
        ga_struct father= new ga_struct();
        father.gene="123";
        newSpecies.vector.add(father);

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            ga_struct ng = new ga_struct();        
            ng=newSpecies.mutate(father);
            ng.fitness=i;
            newSpecies.vector.add(ng);
            father=ng;          
            System.out.println(newSpecies.vector.get(i).gene+" with fitness factor "+newSpecies.vector.get(i).fitness);

        }

        newSpecies.sortspecies();
        System.out.println("\ncurrent population\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(newSpecies.vector.get(i).gene+" with fitness factor "+newSpecies.vector.get(i).fitness);
        }
```

The mutator function just alter the `String(gene)` one character at a time. I just mutated 9 new species from the "father" in the first loop. But.. I dont know why the output of the code is giving me this-

```
133 with fitness factor 1
433 with fitness factor 2
433 with fitness factor 3
443 with fitness factor 4
453 with fitness factor 5
553 with fitness factor 6
563 with fitness factor 7
563 with fitness factor 8
573 with fitness factor 9

current population

573 with fitness factor 9
573 with fitness factor 9
573 with fitness factor 9
573 with fitness factor 9
573 with fitness factor 9
573 with fitness factor 9
573 with fitness factor 9
573 with fitness factor 9
573 with fitness factor 9
573 with fitness factor 9
```

The first loop is proof that mutation is going slowly.. And i also added immediately after a mutation, then why is that later on all of them are just overwritten by the latest edition?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the only thing that happens between the two sets of printlns is the call to `sortSpecies()`.  So maybe you should show us what that method is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your object usage is a bit weird.

In mutate, you seem to be changing and returning the father.

This means your list will contain multiple references to the same instance.

to clarify:

```
public ga_struct mutate(ga_struct parent) //takes in reference to parent
{
    Random r= new Random(); //modifies parent
    ......     do some modification to the parent
    return parent; //return reference to parent
}
```

And in your main:

```
    ga_ newSpecies = new ga_();
    Random r= new Random(10);
    ga_struct father= new ga_struct();//instantiate father
    father.gene="123";
    newSpecies.vector.add(father);

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        ga_struct ng = new ga_struct();//create new instance for child
        ng=newSpecies.mutate(father);//set ng as reference to same instance as father, instance instantiated on previous line is discarded
        ng.fitness=i;
        newSpecies.vector.add(ng);
        father=ng;          
        System.out.println(newSpecies.vector.get(i).gene+" with fitness factor "+newSpecies.vector.get(i).fitness);

    }
```

Try Something more like this:

```
    public ga_struct mutate(ga_struct parent)
{
    ga_struct ng = new ga_struct();
    ng.gene = father.gene;
    Random r= new Random();
    //do some modification to ng
    return ng;
}
```

and in your main:

```
a_ newSpecies = new ga_();
    Random r= new Random(10);
    ga_struct father= new ga_struct();
    father.gene="123";
    newSpecies.vector.add(father);

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {    
        ga_struct ng=newSpecies.mutate(father);
        ng.fitness=i;
        newSpecies.vector.add(ng);
        father=ng;          
        System.out.println(newSpecies.vector.get(i).gene+" with fitness factor "+newSpecies.vector.get(i).fitness);

    }

    newSpecies.sortspecies();
    System.out.println("\ncurrent population\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(newSpecies.vector.get(i).gene+" with fitness factor "+newSpecies.vector.get(i).fitness);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. my apologies for being such a poor coder!.. anyway the following solved my problem-
parent.gene= origin.gene;
        
instead of
parent= origin;

why is it? actually

Comment: parent = origin means parent and origin will point to the same object.
parent.gene = origin.gene will change the value of the primitive gene.  If you go over some of this, it may help: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating a new object, you've added the father object 9 times to the vector.

Essentially what you've got is

father -> obj@123

What your List object looks like is
[ obj@123, obj@123, obj@123, ... ]

You're going to need to create new instances to record this.  I would recommend implementing the "clone()" method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You're working with a single object everywhere, you never add a new `ga_struct` instance to the list. Your `mutate()` method appears to simply modify the `parent` parameter and returns it - it's still the same object, just modified, which means it's modified everywhere.

```
public ga_struct mutate(ga_struct parent)
{
    Random r= new Random();
    ......     do some modification to the parent
    return parent;
}
```

You do create a new instance of `ga_struct` but you immediately overwrite it by setting the reference to the mutated `father` (which is still the same instance, just modified):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        ga_struct ng = new ga_struct();        
        ng=newSpecies.mutate(father); //the new ga_struct is overwritten
        ng.fitness=i;
        newSpecies.vector.add(ng);
        father=ng;          
        System.out.println(newSpecies.vector.get(i).gene+" with fitness factor "+newSpecies.vector.get(i).fitness);

    }
```

Your output in this loop seems to work because you see the modifications to `father` in the order they happen. **However, what you're actually doing is just adding references to the same (modified) object over and over into the `List`.**

Thus, when you finally print them all out, you see 10 duplicate entries in the `List`.

---

My suggestion is to change `mutate()` to return a new instance of `ga_struct` - you could either create a new object and set it's `gene` field to be the mutated `gene` field from `parent`. Or you could [`clone`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) `parent` and *then* change the clone's gene string. In either case, you will end up returning a new instance of `ga_struct` which should fix the problem.

```
public ga_struct mutate(ga_struct parent)
{
    Random r= new Random();
    ga_struct mutant = parent.clone(); 
   //or 
   //ga_struct mutant = new ga_struct();
   //mutant.gene = parent.gene;

    ......     do some modification to the mutant
    return mutant; //now you'll be returning a new object not just a modified one
}
```

Comment: Technically he does but then immediately discards it. This is the right idea though.

Comment: He creates new `ga_struct` in at least two places in the code.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer You're right, I should rephrase that - I meant to point out that he seems to be working with the same instance everywhere (he overwrites the new object as @DHall points out) - thus modifying it in each iterations leads to having 10 entries in the `List` all of which are the same object.